# any of composer require command not working

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I am using Laravel Valet to creating laravel application because suddenly composer "create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel blog" not working.
require command not working.
so I install the valet
The composer is successfully installed on my device Globally. i Follow stap from laravel valet doc to setup composer.
Problem is after composer require command it takes minimum 5min to load 
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
and nothing happened I wait 30min and not error or no output
check images [composer installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJPbL.png)

[again wait for 1hour no output and no error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sw9vW.png)

[one more example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nvkn.png)

now how to fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solved. It was my broadband problem. The connection was alright but it was not able to download package. now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a network error. You should check your network settings, double check if you have access. (I think you have because you posted this question)

There could also be something wrong with the installed composer repositories. If one of those is unavailable it will take forever to load all repositories/search for a repository. You can check which repositories are used with the following command:

```
composer -g config repositories
composer config repositories
```

Comment: after run composer config repositories [RuntimeException]                                               
  File "./composer.json" cannot be found in the current directory

Comment: The command without `-g` is only for project specific configuration. Most of the time you don't use this. You can try it in the project folder where you find these problems

Comment: check this:~:cd builds/forum
forum:composer -g config repositories
{"packagist.org":{"type":"composer","url":"https?:\/\/repo.packagist.org","allow_ssl_downgrade":true}}
forum:composer require laravel/socialite   It is still not working...         and code of composer.json file {
    "require": {
        "laravel/installer": "^2.0",
        "laravel/valet": "^2.0"
    }
}

Comment: Is `composer install` still not showing any output?

Comment: Composer could not find a **composer.json** file in /Users/sazu

Comment: Again, do this in the project folder where you experience this problems

Comment: yes. **composer install** working but **composer require laravel/socialite** not wroking

Comment: What does `composer require laravel/socialite` say in the response?

Comment: nothing. just IDLE and after 5min it  show'./composer.json has been updated Loading composer repositories with package information Updating dependencies (including require-dev)' and again IDLE

Comment: This means your process is running abnormally slow. I do not think it is really running IDLE. Maybe you should try some virus scanners and/or turning it off and on again? Not really sure what to do here sorry